# passing array from javascript to php

Tags: javascript, php

I am trying to pass an `array()` on PHP from JavaScript but PHP receives nothing. It always sets `$str` to `""`. Why?

**JavaScript**

```
 var ArrayPassedID = [];
 function pass(){ 
    $.ajax({
        url: 'http://mysite/index2.php?task=getPassed',
        type:'get',
        dataType:'json',
        data: {id: JSON.stringify(ArrayPassedID)},
        async: false,
        success: function(response){ 
            ArrayPassedID.push(response.id);
    }

 ....
```

**PHP**

```
$str = "";
if(!empty($_POST["id"])){
    $id = $_POST["id"];
    $id = json_decode($id,true);
    $str = implode(",",$id);
}     

$data = query(SELECT id, response FROM `conversation` WHERE id not in ('".$str ."'));
$values = array();
$values['id'] = $data['id'];
$values['response'] = $data['response'];
return json_encode($values);
```

Comment: what if you change to `data: JSON.stringify({id:ArrayPassedID});`

Comment: Your ajax: `type:'get',` and your PHP `$_POST`...change one or the other and see what happens :)

Comment: i see..let me try..:)

Comment: you were right./.thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From Javascript, you send data with `GET` method of HTTP protocol.
From PHP, you retrieve data from global `$_POST`, which correspond to `POST` method.
Use same method in the two ways.

in ajax (js) :

```
type:"POST"
```

Comment: i still got problem.. on my console it show list of id...id must not be repeating.. but i get 64,65,63,62,62,62,63,65,63,63

Comment: you can remove duplicate ids server side, with native PHP function array_unique() http://php.net/manual/fr/function.array-unique.php